# how to send body parameter with multipart file upload request usin ion library?

Tags: android, android-ion

This is the first time ever I am using multi part request to upload data on the server.I am using ion for service hit can you please let me know how can I post my data on the server?
This is my request parameter

```
jSON Request:
 {s_id 
note_name
 file_name 
tag_name 
set_date 
mark_as_done
 clear_reminder
 Description 
media_name1 
media_name2
 media_name3
 Count = 3 }
```

Along with it, I have to upload file media1, media2, media2 on same api**. Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Still looking for your replay...

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a JSON body and a Multipart body in one HTTP request.

you can send your json as a parameter :)

```
// first create your json object
    JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
    object.addProperty("note_name", "your value goes here");
    object.addProperty("description", "your description goes here");
    // add other stuffs here

    //create list of files to upload
    List<Part> files = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        files.add(new FilePart("file" + i, new File("path of file like: storage/image/....")));
    }

    Ion.with(context)
            .load("POST","http://example.com")
            .uploadProgress(new ProgressCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(long downloaded, long total) {
                    int percent = (int) (downloaded * 100 / total);
                    // update your progressbar with this percent if needed
                }
            })
            .addMultipartParts(files)
            .setMultipartParameter("json", object.toString()) // your json is here
            .asString()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        // error: log the message here
                        return;
                    }
                    if (result != null) {
                        // result is the response of your server
                    }
                }
            });
```

Hope this help you :)